# Display Mongodb collection in jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I'm new in node.js and mongodb. 
I set a mongodb collection called "article". I would like to display all the article of this collections in a jade template. I used this code :

server.js:

```
articles: db.article.find()
```

index.jade:

```
-for article in articles
      .row
        .twelve.columns
          .panel
            li= article.text
```

The jade is really basic but that will change. The fact is, when I run this code, the list in the jade template is empty and nothing is display. It looks like the variable 'articles' is empty.

Does anyone know how can I make that working?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.find()` is asynchronous. you are using it synchronously.

```
function(req, res, next) {
  db.articles.find().toArray(function(err, articles) {
    res.render('page', {
      articles: articles
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
- console.log(articles)
```

In your template to figure out if the array is empty!

Comment: I tried that, in the console, I have this result:
'{ _oncursor: { get: [Function], put: [Function] } }'

Comment: what module do you use for accessing your mongodb ?

Comment: you must be what is db here ? did you require mongodb-native or mongoose or ?

Comment: oh yes mongodb-native, I set a login/logout page related to an other collection of my database and working fine. I think my problem comes from here 'articles: db.article.find()' but I really don't know why or how can do that in an other way..

Comment: console.log server side and check you have data.

Comment: try to console.log server side to figure out if you have data.

Comment: I have that : [object Object]

Comment: Have a look at util.inspect, here is a wrapper example https://github.com/dotcloud/express-on-dotcloud/blob/master/app/tools.js